# Retrieve objects from parse not working with Xcode Version 6.3.1

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a problem with retrieving data using Parse.

The compiler says:

> AnyObject? is not convertible to "NSString"

I have tried unwrapping, but when I tried to do that, I got an other compiler error

> NSString is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

I would appreciate any help.

```
   let query = PFQuery(className: "TestObject")
   let fetchedObject =  query.getFirstObject()
   var name: String
   if let fetchedName = fetchedObject["User"] as? NSString {
       name = fetchedName
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getFirstObject() return optional object (PFObject?)

try this:

```
 let query = PFQuery(className: "TestObject")
 let fetchedObject = query.getFirstObject()

 var name = fetchedObject?["User"] as? String

 if let name = name {
     println("name is \(name)")
 } else {
     println("don't fetch name")
 }
```